# Is it possible to write Kivy apps for iOS in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I am working on a Python based app using Kivy, and wanted to deploy it on my iPhone to test it out. When I searched for how to do this, I found this site: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html which is on Kivy's official site.

At the top, it says 'Note
Currently, packages for iOS can only be generated with Python 2.7. Python 3.4+ support is on the way.'

Is this info up to date?? If so, is there some way I can deploy the app onto my iPhone using Python 3.6, or will I have to downgrade to Python 2.7?

EDIT: Just wanted to mention, I am on a Mac using PyCharm. I use Python 3.6

Comment: time to change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More up to date answer - yes, you can use python 3.6 now with kivy-ios. I have created and published apps on the app store using python 3.6 and kivy!

Here is an example: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/100-days-of-fitness/id1468049372

100% Python and Kivy :)

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere? A link to a finished app is a good existence proof to answer the question “yes”, but doesn’t suggest how to do it, as the docs [still say](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html) “Currently, packages for iOS can only be generated with Python 2.7. Python 3.4+ support is on the way.“

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. IOS is currently the only kivy platform not ready for python 3 this is do to lacking toolchain requirements and may take a while. There is currently an almost beta release for interfacing some python 3 with kivy using the method:

```
kivy.compat.PY2 = False
```

You can read more about this [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.compat.html). However, I highly recommend you don't use any of these because it's more trouble than it's worth right now especially if you want any stability in your app. Python 2.7 is time tested and stable with kivy though so I recommend this over a shaky beta version.

If you have your heart set on using python 3 then you might want to take a look at [BeeWare](https://pybee.org). It is currently up to date with python 3.6 and is similar to kivy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! 2.7 is similar enough to 3, so I’ll work with that

Comment: It should not be a hard switch and I don't see any massive drawbacks to using 2.7. Also I believe pycharm has tools to convert 3.6 to 2.7 but not 100% sure on that. Did I answer all your questions?

Comment: Actually, I do have 1 more: how did you get this info about why 3 isn’t supported? Before I started this thread, I did a little bit of searching as to why 3 isn’t supported, and a potential reason. Can u send a link for where you found this info, or is it just general knowledge with regular Livy users?

Comment: Some of this is general knowledge but the main reason it's so slow is that nobody has been working on it that's why it's been over two years with nothing to really show https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/137