# What is the best library to write iOS games in Python 3?

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, pygame

I have been writing games in the pygame library for a while on my computer. I have been wanting to begin writing games for iOS that could potentially be put on the App Store. If I were to want to do this in Python, what is the best library to use?

Comment: Can you use Kivy?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386478/is-it-possible-to-write-kivy-apps-for-ios-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options that you can try, such as Kivy, Pymob and maybe BeeWare, but I wouldn't recommend this language to do app development and even less for IOS. My suggestion is to start to learn Dart and use Flutter or React Native that also provides a large variety of options. As far as gamedev, the best and most well-known platform is Unity, using C#.